# Parse.com IOS push notification custom sound

Tags: ios, audio, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

Cant get custom sound to play when a notification is received.
I receive the notification but the default sound is played.
The sound default.caf is added to my Xcode project (just dragged it in and chose copy if needed...). I use cloud code to send notification as shown below. 
I use IOS 9.

```
Parse.Push.send({
                where: query,
                data: {
                    "alert": "Test message...",
                    "sound": "default.caf",
                    "badge": "Increment",
                    "title": "Test"
                }
            });
```

Comment: First, make sure your sound file is added to the "Copy Bundle Resources" in the Build Phases tab of the project settings. The other possibility is the file format. Personally, I always use .m4a.

Comment: Adding it to Copy Bundle Resources did the trick! Thanks :)